# how to fix the calculation error which says 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

im working on football data set and this is following error im getting. please help,

```
#what is the win rate of HomeTeam?





n_matches = df.shape[0]



n_features = df.shape[1] -1

n_homewin = len(df(df.FTR == 'H'))

win_rate = (float(n_homewin) / (n_matches)) * 100

print ("Total number of matches,{}".format(n_matches))
print ("Number of features,{}".format(n_features))
print ("Number of maches won by hom team,{}".format (n_homewin))
print ("win rate of home team,{:.2f}%" .format(win_rate))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-7e4d81fc684e> in <module>
      5 n_features = df.shape[1] -1
      6 
----> 7 n_homewin = len(df(df.FTR == 'H'))
      8 
      9 win_rate = (float(n_homewin) / (n_matches)) * 100
```

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not 
    expected result should print the team winning ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is with `()`, need `[]` for filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
n_homewin = len(df[df.FTR == 'H'])
```

Or simplier count `True`s values by `sum`:

```
n_homewin = (df.FTR == 'H').sum()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help sir, this did work as you said.

Answer (score 0):

you should modify it to `df[df.FTR == 'H']`. The parentheses imply a function call

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this really worked on as you stated.